# Is it legal to multiply left side of equation by $\mathrm{d}y$ and right side by $\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I have a question about calculus rules which I find difficult to find an answer to.
Say I have an equation of $x$ and $y$, e.g.: $y=x^2$. Am I then allowed to multiply the left side by a small change in y and the right side by a small change in $x$: $y\mathrm{d}y=x^2\mathrm{d}x$? If the equation is true, then it should be true for an infinitesimal change in $x$ and $y$, but I am not sure about the Leibnitz notation and how we are allowed to use it in equations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$dx$ and $dy$ are still real numbers, even if they are very small. So $y=x^2$ does not imply that $y\,dy = x^2\,dx$ unless $dx = dy$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x}=2x$

so $\operatorname{d}y=2x\operatorname{d}x$

$y \operatorname{d}y = x^22x\operatorname{d}x$

verifying
$\frac {\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x}=\frac{2x^3}{y}=\frac{2x^3}{x^2}=2x$